# Is there redux-persist API to sync localStorage change to redux-persist?

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage, redux-persist

I have a `Redux` app that uses `redux-persist` to store auth jwt token.
The app will get the token from the redux store to be put to HTTP `Authorization` header.

The problem here is that whenever I login to other user in another tab, the redux store is not updated with the newly logged in user token. (although the `localStorage` is updated with the newly logged in user token)

So I wonder if there is a best practice to do this by setting some options to `redux-persist`?

Or do I need to add a localStorage listener to update the redux store whenever there is a localStorage change?

I hope my explanation is understandable.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no build-in api for this!

You can use `storage` event :

```
import { legacy_createStore as createStore,Store, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import reducer from "./reducer";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import persistStore from "redux-persist/es/persistStore";


const persistConfig = {
    key:"root",
    storage:storage,
    blacklist:["loading"]
}
 
const persistedReducer = persistReducer( persistConfig , reducer );
const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer, 
    {counter:0}, // initial state
);
 
const persistor = persistStore(store);
export {store , persistor};


/* this event update state when storage changed! */
window.addEventListener('storage',(e)=>{
    const persistData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('persist:root'));
    const newCounterValue = parseInt(persistData.counter);
    console.log(newCounterValue);
    store.dispatch({type:'SET_VALUE',payload:newCounterValue})
})
```

other option is `redux-state-sync` package.`redux-state-sync` is a `middleware` for `redux`

```
npm i redux-state-sync
```

in this example when counter changed in `localstorage` , all tab will recieved new state value!

```
import { legacy_createStore as createStore,Store, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import reducer from "./reducer";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import persistStore from "redux-persist/es/persistStore";

import {
    createStateSyncMiddleware,
    initMessageListener,
} from "redux-state-sync";
 
const persistConfig = {
    key:"root",
    storage:storage,
    blacklist:["loading"]
}
 
const persistedReducer = persistReducer( persistConfig , reducer );
const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer, 
    {counter:0}, // initial state
    applyMiddleware(createStateSyncMiddleware())
);

initMessageListener(store);
 
const persistor = persistStore(store);
export {store , persistor};
```

[please see this link for more info](https://github.com/aohua/redux-state-sync)!